Unable to create RestTemplate while upgrading Spring Boot 3.x from http/1.1 to http/2
Unable to Communicate between Spring boot apps in http/2 using RestTemplate.
I have been in the process of Upgrading my Spring boot Micro Services from http/1.1 to http/2.0.
I was able to spin up the servers by below application.properties
#application.properties
server.http2.enabled=true
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=c:\\Keystore\\mykeystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=*****

#App1
server.port=8001

#App2
server.port=8002

I am able to reach the endpoints and receive responses successfully from the two individual apps and also able to verify the http/2.0 protocol by the below logs
App1 - https://localhost:8001/test1 - 200 OK
App2 - https://localhost:8002/test2 - 200 OK
System.out.println("HttpServletRequest protocol"+ request.getProtocol()); //2.0
System.out.println("HTTP protocol: "+ ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getProtocol()); //2.0

Problem is when I connect App2 endpoints through App1 using RestTemplate it is updowngrading to http/1.1 while receiving it in App2
App1 - https://localhost:8081/test3  ---> App2 https://localhost:8082/test3
Sysout("protocol"+ request.getProtocol()); //App1 http/2.0
Sysout("protocol"+ request.getProtocol()); //App2 http/1.1

My current RestTemplateConfig file
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
 PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
 poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateHttpMaxConnection);        
 poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateHttpMaxPerRouteConnection);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
            .build();
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
            .errorHandler(responseErrorHandler())
            .additionalInterceptors(new LoggingInterceptor())
            .build();
}

Tried out few options using CloseableHttpAsyncClient but not succeeded yet
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate1() {
 PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
 poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateHttpMaxConnection);
 poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateHttpMaxPerRouteConnection);

 CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.customHttp2()
        .setTlsStrategy(ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())
                .setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_3)
                .build())
        .setIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom()
                .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
                .build())
        .setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
                .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(10))
                .build())
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(StandardCookieSpec.STRICT)
                .build())
        .build();

  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =   new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
  requestFactory.setHttpClient((HttpClient) client);// this method is not accepting the CloseableHttpClient object
  requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
  requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000);
  return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

}
Few of my dependencies version for reference
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.3.3
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.33
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.28
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:10.1.33
org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.12
org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.3.1
org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:5.2.5
org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-h2:5.2.5

